# Mysql Alias of alias

Tags: mysql, alias

I'm trying to run this *sample* query :
 `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id > 2) AS o1 JOIN o1 AS o2 ON o1.id = o2.id;`

but this error occur:

> Error Code: 1146
>   Table 'pnu.o1' doesn't exist

how should i join the sub query  with itself?

Comment: What are you trying to do, is this only to test what is working? To join the subquery on itself you have to use another subquery containing the same resultset.

Comment: I'm trying to find a workaround to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142287/remove-result-set-doesnt-have-criteria) , as the comment in that post has stated i need to do a self join

Comment: That dba question lacks the schema detail with sample data necessary to solve this efficiently. A self-join is highly unlikely to be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `o1` exists in your DB. You created it as an `alias` but you can not re use this `alias`.

You will have to write this sub-query again and create a new alias of it:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id > 2) AS o1 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id > 2) AS o2 
    ON o1.id = o2.id;
```

Or a temporary table may be an alternative.

Comment: He created it as a `Derived` table

Comment: would you please explain more about *temporary table* solution?

Comment: No i think! in fact im looking for an optimized way

Comment: @Drew Yes he did, but its out of scope of a derived table. You can use it in `WHERE` and `SELECT` but can not in `JOIN`.

Comment: @alex It depends, if you have no other way, you will have to use `temp table`. Define what you want to get and what is you schema, there must be an optimize way.

Comment: You cannot use what in a join? A derived table?

Comment: The way he is using, it'll not JOIN. The way I mentioned, it can be joined.

Comment: Anyway, stay away from correlated subqueries and temporary tables. The performance is dreadful. Over and out my friend.

Comment: Thats why I asked for schema. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: @DownVoter please comment so I could fix whats wrong with it.